# Switched from normal MySql to PDO but can't get the login process to work

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

Alright, so like i said in the title, i decided to use the PDO method over the mysql_query and so on method, but for some reason it keeps returning that the information is incorrect, im not entirely familiar with what could be wrong since this is the first time using PDO, could anyone tell me what's wrong? 
Code:

```
    $user = $user;
    $pass = sha1($pass);
    $sql = "SELECT COUNT(*) FROM users WHERE `username` = :username and `password` = :password";
    $result = $db->prepare($sql);
    $result->execute(array(":username"=>$_POST['username'], ":password"=>$_POST['pass']));

    $num=$result->fetchColumn();
    if($num == 0)
    {
        $message="The information you entered is incorrect";
    }
    else
    {
        $_SESSION['pass'] = $pass;
        $num = $result->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
        while($row = $num)
        {
            $username = $row['username'];
            $id = $row['id'];
        }
        $_SESSION['username'] = $username;
        $_SESSION['id'] = $id;

        if($remember == "yes")
        {
            setcookie("id_cookie", $id, time()+60*60*24*100, "/");
            setcookie("pass_cookie", $pass, time()+60*60*24*100, "/");
        }

        header("Location: home.php");
```

Comment: `session_start();` loaded?

Comment: Yeah, I have it loaded.

Comment: I'd use `rowCount()` instead of `fetchColumn()`

Comment: Consider `password_hash()` instead of storing plain passwords.

Answer (score 3):

`fetchColumn()` returns the next (or specified via column number argument) column or `false` if no result found. This is typically a string as per [the return value format from the docs](http://php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.fetchcolumn.php).

By loose comparison (match up any string with the `0` in the loose comparison table [found here](http://php.net/manual/en/types.comparisons.php)), if `$num = 'any string';` by the output of `fetchColumn()`, then `$num == 0` evaluates to `true`.

I believe you are looking to use [`rowCount()`](http://php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.rowcount.php):

```
$num = $result->rowCount();
if($num == 0) {
    // ...
```

However a warning from the docs:

> If the last SQL statement executed by the associated PDOStatement was a SELECT statement, some databases may return the number of rows returned by that statement. However, **this behaviour is not guaranteed for all databases and should not be relied on for portable applications.**

and `COUNT(*)` will always return at one result, so `$num` will always end up being `1`.

**If you want to fetch the value of the `COUNT(*)`** you will have an easier time assigning it to an alias:

```
$sql = "SELECT COUNT(*) AS found_rows FROM users WHERE `username` = :username and `password` = :password";
```

and then fetching that value:

```
$num = $result->fetch(PDO::FETCH_OBJ)->found_rows;
```

As @Mario points out and you say yourself, you do in fact have some serious logical problems with your code. It would take too much time to explain each mistake, but here's a better revision that may help you in the right direction:

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM users WHERE `username` = :username and `password` = :password";
$result = $db->prepare($sql);
$result->execute(array(":username"=>$_POST['username'], ":password"=>$_POST['pass']));

$user = $result->fetch(PDO::FETCH_OBJ); // Returns false-y value if data set is empty
if(empty($user))
{
    $message="The information you entered is incorrect";
}
else
{
    $pass = sha1($user->password);
    $_SESSION['pass'] = $pass;
    $username = $user->username;
    $id = $user->id;
    $_SESSION['username'] = $username;
    $_SESSION['id'] = $id;

    if($remember == "yes")
    {
        setcookie("id_cookie", $id, time()+60*60*24*100, "/");
        setcookie("pass_cookie", $pass, time()+60*60*24*100, "/");
    }

    header("Location: home.php");
}
```

Comment: Ah thanks, that worked, just have a few things that I need to fix thanks!

Comment: @mario Right and I noticed he's using `COUNT(*)`.. adding in a bit more to my answer momentarily..

Comment: @mario OP states above that it worked. *"Ah thanks, that worked, just have a few things that I need to fix thanks!"*

Comment: so what if it yields `(COUNT(*) = 0)`, the rowCount is still > 0. but there are no rows found

Comment: @Fred-ii- It's more of the non-guaranteed row count that's the issue I see

Comment: Thanks @Ghost - I was more focused on the `fetchColumn` issue first and everything else is waterfalling.

Comment: @sjagr and a sidenote: `$row['username'];` doesn't make sense, its not even added on the column selected anyway. should just straight up use `SELECT *` then use `!empty()` on `->fetch()`, so that index could be accessed.

Comment: @Ghost Agreed - OP certainly has a lot more code to review but I'd argue it's out of the scope of the original problem. Nonetheless I'm going to rewrite his snippet the best I can in a moment

Comment: @sjagr yes thats more plausible this is what i'm going to write earlier but this seems to cover all bases, should get this one up and running good. +1